# How to align a dropdown in CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am making a website and I want to make a drop-down list but I have a trouble.
I want to do something like this:

Option A Option B Option C Option D Option E

and a dropdown list to B with 4 options but when I do it, it looks like that:

Option A Option B 
.....................Option 1

.....................Option 2

.....................Option 3

.....................Option 4

...........................................Option C Option D Option E

this is my code:

```css
.option {
  display: inline-block;
}

.option>li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>

    <ul>

      <div class="option">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">3D</a>
              <li><a href="#">2D</a>
                <li><a href="#">Websites</a>
                  <li><a href="#">IT help</a>
          </ul>

          </li>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
      </div>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
</nav>
```

Comment: You should focus on valid HTML First, a ul can't include a div as direct child. Only li allowed

Comment: once you fixed your HTML and still use inline-block, mind vertical-align. top will then fix your alignment in between inline-block boxes of different contents and heights.

Answer (score 1):

### Restructure your HTML

1. Close your `li` tags. Make sure you are closing them properly like
   this:

   ```html
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   ```
2. Nest all of the top level menu items (Home, Services, Gallery, Contact, About Me) in a single `ul`

Your HTML should look something like this

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">3D</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2D</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Websites</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">IT help</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

---

### Add style

1. Add a class to the Services `li` to indicate that it is a dropdown. I am calling mine `dropdown`
2. Remove those pesky dots on each list item using `list-style: none; padding: 0;`
3. To arrange the top level `ul` horizontally, make it a flexbox by applying `display: flex;` on the `ul`. I would also add `flex-wrap: none;` to make sure the list does not try to wrap its elements on small screens.
4. I recommend giving each element of the flexbox a constant width and aligning the text how you like like. I used `width: 80px; text-align: center;`
5. Lastly, hide the elements of your dropdown by setting the inner `ul`'s `display` to `none`. And show the dropdown by setting `display` to `block`. I did this using the class `open`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: none;
}

nav > ul > li {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav > ul > li.dropdown > ul > * {
  display: none;
}

nav > ul > li.dropdown.open > ul > * {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Services</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">3D</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2D</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Websites</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">IT help</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

---

### Add interaction

Now if you want to actually make the submenu expand, I recommend using JavaScript. In the code snippet above, all you need to do is toggle the class `open` on any `li` with the `dropdown` class.

There are infinite possibilities, but a good place to start is this [W3 Schools tutorial on building clickable dropdown menus](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp). Be mindful of accessibility features as well by reading this [W3 tutorial on building accessible flyout menues](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/#flyoutnavmousefixed).

Here is a tutorial on building a [CSS only accessible dropdown menu](https://moderncss.dev/css-only-accessible-dropdown-navigation-menu/); although I recommend sticking to JS solutions, because they are more versatile.

#### Rudimentary example using JS

```js
const dropdownMenuItems = document.querySelectorAll("li.dropdown");

const toggleDropdown = (e, el) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("dropdown-control")) {
    el.classList.toggle("open");
  }
};

dropdownMenuItems.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => toggleDropdown(e, el));
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: none;
}

nav > ul > li {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav > ul > li.dropdown > ul > * {
  display: none;
}

nav > ul > li.dropdown.open > ul > * {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-control">Services</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">3D</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2D</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Websites</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">IT help</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

### Closing thoughts

I kept the styling really barebones. You can of course style however you like. It seems like you are mostly asking about how to get the arrangement right.

It probably makes sense to change the Services `a` tag to a `button` if it does not behave like a link. This is important for screen readers to know how to treat that element.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it: It's a little bare, but it works. I would make each `li` have the class of `option` and get rid of the `div`s so that it is more consistent and simpler. Also, you were missing all of your closing `li` tags, which messed some things up. I also added a simple `:hover` mechanism so that it will hide and show when you hover over it.

```css
.option {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 75px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.contains-dropdown:hover > .dropdown{
  display: block
}

option>li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>

    <ul>

      <li class="option"><a href="#">Home</a></li>


      <li class="option contains-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Services</a>

        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">3D</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2D</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Websites</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">IT help</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>

      <li class="option"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>

      <li class="option"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

      <li class="option"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
</nav>
```

Comment: Careful, this approach relies on mouse hover, so non-mouse users will not be able to interact with it.